# Form gets submitted on ENTER button

Tags: java, html, django

I have form as given below. Now, when I enter something in the #search_string and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button it automatically takes it to the `action=Paid`... I'm not sure why the form gets submitted on the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button..

```
   <!--<div id="startsearchbox">-->
            <form id="bigsearchform_new" method="post" action="Paid">
                    <!--<label style="display:none" for="search_string">SEARCH</label>-->
                    <input id="search_string" name="search_string" type="text" class="startnewsearch rounded" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="500" >
                    <input id="searchButton1"  type="button" class="searchButton" title="Click here to search the database">
                    <input type="hidden" name="antiCSRF" value="{{acsrf}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="{{session_id}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="commodity_id" id="commodity_id" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Because the enter button is another way of the browser detecting pressing the submit button

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's default behavior of the browser to submit the form on <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button. If you want to prevent form submitssion use `onSubmit` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior for an HTML form, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission