# Form submission on ENTER key button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form that needs to be submitted only if the session is valid...Im uusing the below code..I want to understand if the FORM will be submitted or not when the "ENTER" button will be pressed...

Which one is correct?

1.The form will be submitted and we capture the "ENTER" button event.

or

2.The form will not be submitted and we capture the "ENTER" button event.

```
 $('input[id=search_string]').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert('Pressed Enter KEY')

   }
   });
```

HTML Form code

```
<form id="bigsearchform_new" method="post" action="Paid" >
                        <label style="display:none" for="search_string1">SEARCH</label>
                        <input id="search_string" name="search_string1" type="text" class="startnewsearch rounded" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="500" >
                        <input id="searchButton1"  type="button" class="searchButton" title="Click here to search the database">
                        <input type="hidden" name="antiCSRF" value="{{acsrf}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="{{session_id}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="commodity_id" id="commodity_id" />
                </form>
```

Comment: If the `form` has just one `input`, it will be submitted. If not, you need to handle the functionality.

Comment: Not sure why you don't just implement it and find out for yourself.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` maybe??

Comment: use the onSubmit event instead of keypress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form gets submitted on ENTER button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25249822/)

Comment: Read this: http://designwithpc.com/post/7613217129/submit-a-form-with-enter-using-jquery-keypress

Comment: Use the submit event on the `form`. Like `$("#bigsearchform_new").on("submit" function() {...`. Then you can `return true;` if the form is valid and `return false;` and throw up some validation messages if it is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, use the submit event on the form. Like

```
$("#bigsearchform_new").submit(function() {
    //validate
    if(isValid) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //provide validation message
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then you can `return true;` if the form is valid and `return false;` and throw up some validation messages if it is not valid.

This will have the added benefit of catching the form submission however it may be triggered, whether by the ENTER key press or some other means.